# detect potholes on a road using geohash

Tags: flutter, geohashing

I am trying to develop an app in flutter where it can detect potholes on roads and alert the user about 100 meters before he reaches it.

What my implementation is, i haven taken the coordinates of the each pothole and then created a geohash with precision 9 that means each geohash will be 4.77 mtrs and i will add like 50 of them so that it can be almost 250 mtrs and gps will be able to detect it and i can divide the road in half and only one side of the road  can be detected at a time.

But the problem is coordinates are not precise enough and they jump around a lot to determine which side of the road i am in

so in my app i am asking for 3 permissions ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION and ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION but stil not able to get a precise location

in my app i even know which direction i am facing but still not able to do much

so there any other way to get precise location or any other way to solve the problem